# Is there a function option that will set the release version from a command line parameter in bash?

Tags: bash

I want to set a release version from a command line parameter. A function that will set the release version from a command line parameter.

version=2.5.45

Comment: Which release version ? The one of bash ?`The one of your shell script ? We need more information in order to be able to help you

Comment: Generally No. The script will be provided with a variable called `VERSION=maj.min.rel` where `maj`, `min`, `rel` are traditionally the major and minor software version numbers and `rel` is the release number for that combination. It is part of the script for that period of time and it designates what features, etc.. are available. You can make it changeable, but that defeats a large part of its purpose. Something like `VERSION="{3.4.12:-$1}"` to replace the script version with what you provide on the command line.... Not really recommended...

Comment: The release version is the one of my shell script. For example version (2.5.45). An option that will set the release version from a command line parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can set variables in a function as well. In bash, variables in a function are by default global, unless explicitly declared with `local`. You may explicitly declare them as global:

```
set_version() {
  if [[ -n ${1:-} ]]
  then
    typeset -g version=$1
  else
    echo No version supplied 1>&2
    return 1
  fi
}
```

This can be called by

```
set_version 4711
```